# Заполнение массива нечетными числами c++

Tags: c++, массивы

Есть интовый массив `a[9]`. Сделал такую реализацию заполнения массива только нечетными числами начиная с 1. Кажется чутка замудрил, есть идеи как можно реализовать более рациональным путем?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 9;
    int a[SIZE];
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while (j < SIZE)
    {
        if (i % 2 != 0)
        {
            a[j] = i;
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Не пишите константы в верхнем регистре, это антипаттерн

Comment: Наиболее рационально: `int a[] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17};` :)

Comment: @alexolut чревато ошибками при изменении размера массива

Comment: @Slava понятно, что при б**о**льших размерах надо генерить, но для небольших `n`, я считаю, вполне подходит.

Answer (score 6):

```
const int SIZE = 9;
int a[SIZE];
for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
    a[i] = 2*i+1;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int arr[9] = { 1 };

    for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++){
        arr[i] = arr[i - 1] + 2;
    }

    // вывод
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

результат:

[image: result]

Answer (score 4):

```
const size_t sz = 9;
int arr[sz];
for(int i{0}, j{1}; i < sz; i++, j += 2){
   arr[i] = j;
   std::cout << arr[i] << '\t';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int n = 1;
std::generate( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ), [&n] { auto t = n; n+= 2; return t; } );
```